# How do I install os specific packages inside docker?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-15.10

I am using ubuntu 15.10 and was trying to use docker to setup my node and mongo environments. But since `lsb_release -a` command doesn't work inside docker I was not able to know the version of ubuntu docker image has. It was tagged as `ubuntu:latest`. Also `/etc/lsb-release` utility shows permission denied inside docker.

Is there a way to know which ubuntu version is present inside docker container because for installing mongo I need the name of version to add e.g. for 14.04

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
RELEASE=$(cat /etc/lsb-release  | grep DISTRIB_RELEASE  | cut -d= -f2)
```

I just tried it on my ubuntu:latest docker image and got version 16.04

```
$ docker run -it ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
6d28225f8d96: Pull complete
166102ec41af: Pull complete
d09bfba2bd6a: Pull complete
c80dad39a6c0: Pull complete
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:5718d664299eb1db14d87db7bfa6945b28879a67b74f36da3e34f5914866b71c
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:latest
```

And here is the output

```
root@9c4c1e6313ce:/# RELEASE=$(cat /etc/lsb-release  | grep DISTRIB_RELEASE  | cut -d= -f2)
root@9c4c1e6313ce:/# echo $RELEASE
16.04
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for ubuntu:

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

for alpine:

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
```